# Error in using "histc" - matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I already have a histogram, and would like to use `histc` instead of `hist` as the later gives me the center values of the bins.

When I run the following command:

```
>> [h, bins] = histc(H)
```

I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> histc
Not enough input arguments.
```

Why is that? What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering if i helped with your problem? upvote my answer/mark as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a variable edges: (Matlab Help) :

```
N = histc(X,EDGES), for vector X, counts the number of values in X
that fall between the elements in the EDGES vector (which must contain
monotonically non-decreasing values).  N is a LENGTH(EDGES) vector
containing these counts.
```

Its should be a two long array ie something like `[2 4]` where the upper and lower bounds are 2 and 4 respectively.